# Vim startup project files - bash script

Tags: bash, shell, vim

This program is supposed to open 3 vim terminals with 3 files opened in each one. I have a startup.txt file in each subfolder with the name of each file that I want to startup. ( one name on each line )

**Problems that need to be fixed:**

How can I make the command on line 22 executable? It gives me the following errors when I try to run this command ( it opens the first file in each startup.txt though )

---

**Error:**

/home/george/bin/project: line 17: vsp: command not found

/home/george/bin/project: line 19: vsp: command not found

/home/george/bin/project: line 17: vsp: command not found

/home/george/bin/project: line 19: vsp: command not found

---

**Updated code:**

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 ADDR_FILE=~/Documents/CEDA         #address to the file
  4 ADDR_CEDA=$ADDR_FILE/ceda_lib      #address for ceda_lib
  5 ADDR_GENERAL=$ADDR_FILE/general    #address for general
  6 ADDR_CLI=$ADDR_FILE/CLI            #address for CLI
  7 
  8 function getFile
  9 {
 10     awk 'NR=='$1 $2/startup.txt
 11 }
 12 
 13 for i in $ADDR_CEDA $ADDR_GENERAL $ADDR_CLI; do
 14     CMD_2=""
 15     CMD_3=""
 16     if [ $(getFile 2 $i) ]; then                    #checks if line 2 isn't blank
 17         CMD_2=-c "vsp $i/$(getFile 2 $i)"
 18         if [ $(getFile 3 $i) ]; then                #checks if line 3 isn't blank
 19             CMD_3=-c "vsp $i/$(getFile 3 $i)"
 20         fi
 21     fi
 22     gnome-terminal -e "vim $i/$(getFile 1 $i) $CMD_2 $CMD_3"
 23 done
```

**Example startup.txt:**

```
file1.cpp
file2.hpp
file3.hpp
```

*Please note that I'm a beginner in bash scripting. Any general advice would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: You probably want `xterm -e "vi something" &` three times for 3 terminals.

Comment: You had `vim -c` before, now the `-c` has gone. Also, you need `&` at the end of the `gnome-terminal` line.

Comment: the -c is still there but outside the quotes. -c "vsp $i/$(getFile 2 $i)"

Where shall I put the "&"? what does "&" do?

Comment: `&` goes at the end of the line starting `gnome-terminal` so that the terminal runs in the background and the second one can start before the first one exits - i.e. so the three terminals run in parallel.

Comment: But the terminals start just fine. My problem is that on a previous version of the script all (7 atm) files opened each one in a different terminal. Now 3 start up ( that's what I want) but the other files don't open in split windows inside the same terminal inside vim. Can I use the "&" to execute a second command on the same terminal without starting another terminal? Like executing the "vsp file" command inside an already opened vim session.

Comment: I updated the file fixing a foolish mistake. Now this is the problem that I'm facing.

Comment: To debug your script try running `bash -xv yourScript`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `vim` exactly as I don't use that syntax, but here are some hints.

Your `getline()` function can easily be replaced with a simple `sed` command. If `file` contains:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Try running:

```
sed '2!d' file
```

and you will see it deletes all lines other than line 2. So, your `vim` command starts to look like this:

```
vim -c vsp $i/$(sed '2!d' $i)
```

If you want three `xterm`s, you need to start three, and tell each one to execute a new `vim`. If you want them all running at once, you will need to background them with `&` at the end. That means your script is starting to look like this:

```
for i in "file1" "file2" "file3" ; do
   xterm -e "vim -c vsp $i/$(sed '2!d' $i) ... " &
done
```

Comment: I wanted it to be more intuitive, that's why I made the function (+ I learned how to make functions :D ). Now I'm facing different problems with my code. I will update the question above so check it again please :D

Answer (score 1):

**Working code:**

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 ADDR_FILE=~/Documents/CEDA         #address to the file
  4 ADDR_CEDA=$ADDR_FILE/ceda_lib      #address for ceda_lib
  5 ADDR_GENERAL=$ADDR_FILE/general    #address for general
  6 ADDR_CLI=$ADDR_FILE/CLI            #address for CLI
  7 ADDRESSES="$ADDR_CEDA $ADDR_GENERAL $ADDR_CLI"
  8 
  9 if [ $1 ]; then                                         #checks for parameters
 10     if [ $1 = "-f" ] || [ $1 = "--files" ]; then
 11         for i in $ADDRESSES; do
 12         nautilus $i &
 13         done
 14         exit 0                                          #end script
 15     fi
 16 fi
 17 
 18 function getFile
 19 {
 20     awk 'NR=='$1 $2/startup.txt
 21 }
 22 
 23 for i in $ADDRESSES; do
 24     CMD_2=""
 25     CMD_3=""
 26     if [ $(getFile 2 $i) ]; then                    #checks if line 2 isn't blank
 27         CMD_2="-c \"vsp $i/$(getFile 2 $i)\""
 28         if [ $(getFile 3 $i) ]; then                #checks if line 3 isn't blank
 29             CMD_3="-c \"vsp $i/$(getFile 3 $i)\""
 30         fi
 31     fi
 32     gnome-terminal -e "vim $i/$(getFile 1 $i) $CMD_2 $CMD_3"
 33 done
```

I will add more to it over time but it does the bare minimum of what I wanted it to do :D Thanks for all your help guys!

*PS: I've edited my question quite some times.*